# Play Framework 2: How to access the domain where the app is running

Tags: playframework-2.0

here's my problem: I'm planning to deploy the same app on different domains (different servers). Please, don't ask why... just take it as it is ;)

Well I need the two app to load different cfg files and I'd like do use the site domain as a key to load the correct cfg file on startup.

How can I access this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem setting an environment variable in the OS:

See this link for further details

https://github.com/typesafehub/config#optional-system-or-env-variable-overrides

I opted for this solution because I needed both:
    - a main big set of configuration data to be shared by all the instances
    - a custom small set of configuration data specific for each instance

I ended up in:
    1) creating a single JSON file containing an Array of all the customized settings
 
    2) setting an ENV variable containing the domain name of the application.
        I used the ENV variable as the key to access this JSON array.

In my OS:

```
export ENV_VAR='www.mydomain2.net'
```

In my application.conf:

```
my.domain.name=${?ENV_VAR}
```

My JSON is something like:

```
{ "domains": [
    "www.mydomain1.net": { "setting1": "aValue1", "setting2": "aValue2" },
    "www.mydomain2.net": { "setting1": "aValue3", "setting2": "aValue4" }
]}
```

Comment: So, why didn't you just use the built in configuration api? You could make a base configuration with common stuff and then just include them in the respective domain config and override what is different per domain.

Answer (score 0):

You normally only have access to that through the host in the request, so that does not cut it for you. I'd just point out the domain specific config file with the config-file-system properties when starting each instance of the app.

Check out for the config file selection properties:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Configuration

The staged app starter script takes `-Dsystem.property.name=value` and forwards it to the jvm so you should be able to use that.

Comment: I've investigated about your suggestion, and I came to the conclusion it doesn't suit my needs. As I told, I need do read data from a configuration file, but these data are just a small subset of all the application data, so I'd like to have a main config file (for all the instances) and some additional config files (one per instance). Thanks to the link you gave me, I run into this page where they explain how to read ENV variables from the CFG file. Well, I was thinking about setting an environment variable in order to access the specific file from the application. What about this solution?